# I am receiving a 503 when accessing the cloud datastore from a java app using a service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to access DataStore service using gcloud's Datastore Java API. For 2 of my projects, it works fine, but for one of them, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
Backend Error
```

I am authenticated using a freshly created service account that has the same role, which works for other 2 projects.

Below is how I am building the Datastore service instance:

```
DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
.projectId(projectName)
.authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(jsonKeyFileInputStream))
.build();

options.service();
```

Can someone hint what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I should add that:  

1) "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)" is enabled (today, some time back).  

2) Billing is enabled for the project  

3) I tried using datastore API from https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer and it worked fine.

Comment: Which version of the gcloud library are you using?

Comment: gcloud-java-* v0.1.5

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. Can you send your project ID to eddavisson@google.com so I can take a closer look?

Comment: I have sent the project ID by email. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Ed looked at the project details internally to google cloud and confirmed that the app had somehow reached a bad state and it was a known issue that occasionally comes up relating to the use of v1beta2 API. After his fix, the datastore-hitting-with-a-service-account works fine now. Thanks for the help, Ed.